# Triggering Jenkins build failure when there is Python syntax error

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am a newbie at Jenkins, so I would like some advice on how to trigger a Jenkins build failure when there is a Python syntax or compilation error. I currently have a pipeline script that checks out a specified repository and then runs a Python file 'python pycompile.py'. The purpose of pycompile.py is to use a module called compileall (https://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html#module-compileall) to compile all Python source files in a directory and raises a warning when it encounters an error in one of the Python files. Let's say I have a file file.py that has a syntax error and I get a warning when I run 'python pycompile.py'. However, the Jenkins build still succeeds because there is nothing wrong with pycompile.py, but with file.py. How can I trigger the Jenkins build to fail when 'python pycompile.py' detects an error with a Python file in the checked out repo directory?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins build will always be successful if it gets a return status as `0`.
If you want jenkins to stop then the script shall exit with a status `other than 0`. Eg: `exit 1`
So in your case you have 2 options :

1. Executing `python pycompile.py` shall return an exit status as `other than 0` if it gets a syntax error
2. If the above module is not able to return an exit status other than `0` on errors, then you can write your own script and check if there are any errors that were available on step 1 and if there are errors then you can return with an exit other than 0. In this case Jenkins will fail.